# Instantiate class and push to array Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, loading

I'm trying to instantiate all the classes in the scenes directory and add them to my scenes array. So far the code looks like it should work but I get a strange rgexp -ct error that I can't find any answers for online. Here's my code

```
class Game
    @scenes = []

    def initialize
        Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__)+"/scenes/*.rb"].each do |file|
            require_relative file
            @scenes << eval("#{file.gsub(".rb", "")}.new()")
        end
    end
end
```

And here's what a scene in the directory looks like. I can require them and see the filenames just fine.

```
class Scene99
    @number = 99
    @text = "This is the first scene."
    @next_scene = 0

    def initialize
        puts "WORKS"
    end
end
```

Here's the Syntax Error about regexp that I get, This only appears when I try to run the eval(...

```
/Users/icetimux/projects/death-at-appledore-towers/lib/death-at-appledore-towers/game.rb:8:in `eval': (eval):1: unknown regexp options - ct (SyntaxError)
        from /Users/icetimux/projects/death-at-appledore-towers/lib/death-at-appledore-towers/game.rb:8:in `block in initialize'
        from /Users/icetimux/projects/death-at-appledore-towers/lib/death-at-appledore-towers/game.rb:6:in `each'
        from /Users/icetimux/projects/death-at-appledore-towers/lib/death-at-appledore-towers/game.rb:6:in `initialize'
        from death-at-appledore-towers.rb:3:in `new'
        from death-at-appledore-towers.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `/scenes/*` may be the culprit. The `*` is an invalid regex option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
@scenes << file.split("/").last.gsub(".rb", "").camelize.constantize.new
```

or with `eval`:

```
@scenes << eval("#{file.split("/").last.gsub(".rb", "").camelize}.new")
```

Im assuming that file is a string like `'./scenes/scene99.rb'` and that you need to get an array of scenes objects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a file named, say, `ct.rb`, then `file` will be `/scenes/ct.rb`, and you will `eval`

```
/scenes/ct.new()
```

which is an illegal `Regexp` literal, it is the same as

```
(/scenes/ct).new()
```

Honestly, I have no idea what that code is even supposed to be doing, so I can't offer a fix, but that's the problem. You are blindly assuming that any filename will be a combination of valid `Regexp` flags (such as `x` or `m`).

Comment: D'OH! how could I look that over. I'm trying to instantiate all classes in a directory and append them to an array. Check out the accepted answer.